# Problema com data Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Meu problema está na conversão de data, veja:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('data_evento')));
```

`echo` do `Input::get('data_evento')`: `14/02/2014`

`echo` do `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('data_evento')))`: `1969-12-31`

Realmente não sei o que está acontecendo.

Comment: O campo `data_evento` está sendo setado? Quais os valores que estão vindo da postagem do formulário?

Comment: @rodrigorigotti está na duvida o valor vindo do formulário é 14/02/2014 e para guardar no banco teria que ficar 2014-02-14

Comment: Se está vindo como "14/02/2014", o `strtotime` não vai entender o formato e dá uma data inválida (unix time = -1, ou seja, "31/12/1969"). O que você pdoe fazer é submeter a data no formato YYYY-MM-DD ou mudar o formato da data depois que ela foi submetida.

Comment: De uma lida em: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon ótima ferramenta para manipulação de data, tudo que você for precisar um dia está ai. p. s: nativo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com php puro na versão **5.3** utlize [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) do [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) para converter o formato de `dd/mm/Y` para `Y-mm-dd`(formato do banco)

```
$data = '14/02/2014';
$data_formatada = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
echo $data_formatada->format('Y-m-d') ."<br>";
```

Comment: Exatamente a solução do problema, muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção também é a utilização da biblioteca `Carbon\Carbon, criada por *Brian Nesbitt*.

Ela vem instalada por padrão no Laravel. Ela é uma melhoria da classe `DateTime` citada acima.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
```

Documentação http://carbon.nesbot.com/

Answer (score -1):

Tenho uma função para isso, pode ser útil para alguém.

```
function date_fmt_back(?string $date): ?string {
  if (!$date) {
     return null;
  }

  if (strpos($date, " ")) {
    $date = explode(" ", $date);
    return implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $date[0]))) . " " . $date[1];
  }

  return implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $date)));
}
```

Comment: Se eu passar uma data inválida, exemplo >  14/13/2021 retornará 2021-13-14. CreateFromFormat citados nos posts acima atendem bem melhor e se por exemplo, utilizando a mesma data 14/13/2021 o método retornará o próximo mês 2022-01-14 ou ainda se enviar a data 32/11/2021 o método retorna 2021-12-02, ou seja, retorna a data com os meses/dias "enviados a mais"